# Convert string to date format so it can be stored in database

Tags: php

Users of my application enters the date in this format

```
12.06.2014.
```

How can I convert that to valid DATETIME and add time so I can store in database.

So far I try to do like this:

```
preg_replace('/./','-',$input['date']) . ' ' . date('H:i:s');
```

But I get an error.

So, how to convert 14.06.2014. to 14-06-2014 18:22:20 in order to store in database

Comment: *"If users of my application enters the date in this format"* - Just don't let them in the first place.

Comment: They need to enter, and there is validation that checks if they entered in this way.

Comment: have you looked into using `explode()`?

Comment: You want whatever date the user enters, with the time-of-day of the current time appended? I.e. Where does `18:22:20` come from?

Comment: BTW, your call to `preg_replace` as-is will convert every character to a `-`. `.` is a special character in regular expressions, meaning any character, for an actual period you would need to escape it, like so `\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**strtotime()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [**date()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is what I would do - but there are a couple other confusing issues with your question.

First, the proper format for DATETIME would not be 14-06-2014 18:22:20, but rather 2014-06-14 18:22:20. Second, where is the 18:22:20 coming from?

So here are a few things that should help solve your problem. To get a DATETIME from a string like you specified, you can do this:

```
$input_date = '12.06.2014.';
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($str));
```

It's that simple - strtotime is pretty good, and will figure out what you mean and date() will format it as specified in it's first parameter - [**see demo**](http://codepad.org/JKr5a3F4).

If for some reason you wanted the format you mentioned - 14-06-2014 18:22:20 - date() will do that too:

```
$datetime = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($input_date));
```

But assuming you want a `mysql` DATETIME, then you want Y-m-d format.

Now, the next question is where are you getting 18:22:20? If you always want that exact time, you could do this:

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d 18:22:20', strtotime($input_date));
```

But I really doubt that's what you want. Instead, perhaps you want the current time, attached to the input date. In that case, you could do this:

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($input_date . date('H:i:s')));
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/kKrP2i8r)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($input['date']));
```

Use that $date variable in your insert query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `list` and `explode`. But where does the time come from? I just suppose it was the current time in system.

```
$date = "12.06.2014";
list($d,$m,$y) = explode(".",$date);

$currentTime = date("H:i:s");
echo $d ."-".$m."-".$y. " " . $currentTime;
```